# What is an "ampersand person"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I found the expression in this video (around 0:56): [Youth & Consequences (Ep 1) - The Hanging Chadwick Part 1](https://youtu.be/h8ZA40pwpMA?t=50s)

> (*Farrah narrating*) That’s Sarah Hurley. She and I almost didn’t make it as friends because of the Sarah and Farrah annoyance. I am not an **ampersand person**. So I got the whole school to call her Hurley.

I know that ampersand is the '&'-sign. But I do not know that this is supposed to mean in this context. Could you explain that to me? Thank you!

Comment: Please include some relevant details in your posts, including a transcript of the dialogue, or a summary of the events. Please see [_Details, Please_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: @Em.: Okay sorry, I am new in ELL. I will pay attention to that the next time. And thanks for editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I'm not an ampersand person** is a very elliptical statement.

When someone likes dogs, or is a so-called "dog-lover",  they're called **a dog person**, or if they like cats, **a cat person**.

> Do you like dogs?
>
> -- No, I'm more of a fish person.

So what that sentence means literally is "I am not a lover of ampersands". "I don't like ampersands".  But figuratively, what the person in that video is saying is "I don't think of myself as half of a duo, and I don't want people to think of me that way."

Here's how that meaning is arrived at...

When two people become known as a duo, especially in popular entertainment, they often get referred to by a "commercial name" that takes this pattern:

name1 **&** name2

It is a kind of "billing", how the name would be represented on a poster advertising a concert, say.

For example, these names from American popular culture from decades past:

Sonny & Cher

Captain & Tenille

Simon & Garfunkel

You can see this tendency to use the ampersand with duos at [this site](https://www.ranker.com/list/best-duos-of-all-time/ariel-kana).